# Solving this partial differential equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I'm stuck on a differential equation and would like help with it:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \Psi(s,x)+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(t,x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial I}\Psi(I,x)$$

where $s+t=I.$

I took an introductory course in ordinary differential equations with some partial differential equations a few years ago. This might be a more difficult problem than I'm used to but I just want to see how someone would reason through a problem like this.

Comment: Is there any relation between $s$, $t$ and $I$? Otherwise this equation doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Yes $s+t=I$. @HansLundmark Why doesn't it make sense without a relation between $s,t$ and $I$?

Comment: Because the left-hand side would be a function of $s$, $t$ and $x$, while the right-hand side would be a function of $I$ and $x$.

Comment: Does the question say the equation holds for all $s$ and $t$ pairs? if yes, then I would strongly suspect a linearity in the derivative of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Multigrid said: if you consider $g(y) =\partial_y \psi(y)$ you have ( ignoring the $x$ which seems to be a red herring): $g(s)+g(t)=g(s+t)$ which more or less implies $g(y)=ay$ for some $a$.

Thus $\psi(y)= {1\over 2}a y^2 +b$ for some $a,b$

Comment: You win for a few minutes while I was still editing my (too long) answer. Both are fundamentally the same. But you should add that your coefficients $a$ and $b$ are functions of $x$.

Comment: @ JJacquelin  I'd upvote you, but I am not registered for some reason :(

Comment: It doesn't matter. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \Psi(s,x)+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(t,x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial I}\Psi(I,x) \tag 1$$
where $s+t=I.$

There is no derivative with respect to $x$, but only with respect to the first variable of the function $\Psi$. Thus the equation $(1)$ is not a PDE. It is an ODE where $x$ is considered as a parameter, just like any other parameters that might exist in the unknown function $\Psi$.
$$\frac{d}{ds}\Psi(s)+\frac{d}{dt}\Psi(t)=\frac{d}{d(s+t)}\Psi(s+t)$$
$$\Psi'(s)+\Psi'(t)=\Psi'(s+t)$$
This is the same function taken for a unique variable say $X$ which name changes : $s,t,I$. Let $\Psi'(X)=\Phi(X)$
$$\Phi(s)+\Phi(t)=\Phi(s+t)$$
An obvious solution of this functional equation is : $\quad\Phi(X)=c\;X\quad$ since $cs+ct=c(s+t)$ . Integrating :
$$\Psi(X)=\frac{c}{2} X^2+C$$
Coming back to equation $(1)$ the parameter $x$ appears into $c$ and $C$ which become functions of $x$ :
$$\boxed{\Psi(X,x)=f(x)X^2+F(x)}$$
$f(x)$ and $F(x)$ are arbitrary functions.

CHECKING :

$\Psi(s,x)=f(x)s^2+F(x)\quad\implies\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \Psi(s,x)=2f(x)s$

$\Psi(t,x)=f(x)t^2+F(x)\quad\implies\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(t,x)=2f(x)t$

$\Psi(I,x)=f(x)I^2+F(x)\quad\implies\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial I} \Psi(I,x)=2f(x)I$

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \Psi(s,x)+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(t,x)=2f(x)s+2f(x)=2f(x)(s+t)=2f(x)I=\frac{\partial}{\partial I}\Psi(I,x)$$
The original equation $\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \Psi(s,x)+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(t,x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial I}\Psi(I,x)$ is satisfied.